# SQLAlchemy outerjoin return Blank column

Tags: sqlalchemy, null, outer-join

I'm learning Python and SQLAlchemy for the last 2 weeks, I made some progress but I'm having an issue I have to idea how to resolve.

I do have a SQLAlchemy query as:

```
query = db.session.query(Inventory, BLColor, BLCategory, BLPart, Location). \
        join(BLColor, Inventory.color_id == BLColor.color_id). \
        join(BLCategory, Inventory.category_id == BLCategory.category_id). \
        join(BLPart, Inventory.part_id == BLPart.ITEMID). \
        outerjoin(Location, Inventory.location_id == Location.loc_id,full=False). \
        filter(Inventory.part_id == part_to_find, Inventory.userid == current_user.userid ).order_by(desc(Inventory.quantity))

dbparts = query.all()
```

Later in my code I assign a variable with the result of this query such as:
`part_form.loc = p.Location.location`

So far all works, the problem arises when the location outer join return nothing.

When everything work and look at the type and content of the `dbparts` variable, I see this

```
dbparts=[(<Inventory 1206>, <BLColor 86>, <BLCategory 26>, <BLPart 3020>, <Location 96>), (<Inventory 1197>, <BLColor 11>, <BLCategory 26>, <BLPart 3020>, <Location 96>), (<Inventory 1201>, <BLColor 10>, <BLCategory 26>, <BLPart 3020>, <Location 96>), (<Inventory 1211>, <BLColor 5>, <BLCategory 26>, <BLPart 3020>, <Location 96>), (<Inventory 1198>, <BLColor 7>, <BLCategory 26>, <BLPart 3020>, <Location 96>), ...
```

But when the location is blank I see this:

```
<class 'list'>
dbparts=[(<Inventory 1218>, <BLColor 11>, <BLCategory 479>, <BLPart 30200>, None)]
```

No more Location !!!
Side question how are those <Inventory 1218>, <BLColor 11> , called ?

So when I try to assign `part_form.loc = p.Location.location`  Python is errors out with the error message `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'location'`

How do I treat this ?

I'd like to do a `if p.Location.location exist then assign the value` but ``` if p.Location.location does not exist, set the value of part_form.loc to 'XXX'